# Delete Ring tone from android list

Tags: android

I done a program to change ring tone of android. The main code is here

```
               k = new File(txtRTC.getText().toString());
                     toneName=k.getName().split(".");

                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                    //nameTone=nameTone("");
                    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
                    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE,k.getName());
                    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg");
                    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Some Artist");
                    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
                    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
                    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
                    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

                    //Insert it into the database
                    uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
                    getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
                    newUri =getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

                    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                      AudioSettings.this,
                      RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                      newUri
                    );
```

But now i had a too long list of ring tones. Please help me to delete some items from the same

Thanks
Vishnu V